# IBM Worklight - What is offline authentication?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I have seen sometimes the concept of "offline authentication" in slides but I have never been able to map it to specific feature.

Now in Worklight 6.1 I see it in a table of features and the support for each platform:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039422

What is offline authentication and how does Worklight implements it? I understand it is not the same as "working offline".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like "Offline authentication" is a reference to [Encrypted Offline Cache](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced-client-side-development)... and the same [can be achieved with JSONStore](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced-client-side-development) as well.

Source: [Enhancing Your Mobile Enterprise Security with IBM Worklight](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/Redbooks.nsf/RedbookAbstracts/tips1054.html?Open)

> **Offline authentication** 
>   When applications are running on mobile devices
>   that are not connected to the network, the need for user
>   authentication still exists. The encrypted cache feature in Worklight
>   can be used to achieve more offline authentication because only the
>   correct passwords can unlock the offline cache.

Theoretically you could devise an authentication flow that uses local secure storage for authentication needs.... I don't know how popular that would be...

Comment: I haven't had a chance to write up the details of offline authentication yet, but an example app using the JSONStore for offline authentication can be found here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/jsonstore_revisited_in_worklight_v6_part_1_the_adapter?lang=en

Comment: I don't quite understand why even provide such a thing as offline (local) authentication... does it not defeat the purpose of authentication, or is less secure?

Comment: The common use case is an app that is initialized in the office (with connectivity and full authentication) then used in the field with no connectivity.  Data in an encrypted JSONStore that was initialized in the office when the app was connected and the user was authenticated can be read/written in the field as long as the user provides the same userid/password that was provided in the office when full server side authentication was used and the JSONStore initialized.

Comment: Seems @IdanAdar is an IBMer, guess who got added to someone's sametime contacts ;)

Comment: Ok, understood, it is related to the encrypted json store feature. David it would be great if you could post here when you update the article.